# Install Ubuntu as dual boot near Windows 10 on Raid0 created by z790 motherboard bios

Tags: dual-boot, windows, raid

I want to install ubuntu near to windows 10 on my raid0 array, windows works great with that after rst driver install on it, but ubuntu sees only 2 not connected nvme disks. Is there a way to add something like rst to ubuntu to teach it see raid0? Thanks for any support

I tried to change some registry values from here https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Also commands from here https://www.overclockers.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-and-linux-on-a-fake-raid-array/